# What were the rules for guards in Schindler's factories?

Tags: 20th-century, holocaust

[Oscar Schindler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oskar_Schindler) was able to leverage money for influence to protect the prisoners in his factories.  In addition to barring guards from his factory floor, he was able to influence when a guard could shoot a prisoner.

Is there a historical record of what exactly those rules were and which were influenced by Schindler?